# Setting up a ListSelectionListener

Tags: java, swing, listselectionlistener

Currently working on a Swing application and I need to use a ListSelectionListener to obtain the currently selected value in a JList. I know how to add it to the JList itself, however no matter what I implement, the compiler cannot find the symbol. Any suggestions?

Source:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class ClientApp extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new ClientApp();
    }


    public ClientApp()
    {
        this.setSize(750,380);
        this.setTitle("Honeydukes Muggle Ordering System");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        JPanel invntryPanel = new JPanel();


        //Creating the array for the invntryPanel Jlist

        String[] candy = {"Acid Pops", "Bat's Blood Soup",
                          "Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans",
                          "Blood-flavoured Lollipops",
                          "Cauldron Cakes", "Charm Choc",
                          "Chocoballs", "Chocolate Cauldrons",
                          "Chocolate Frogs", "Chocolate Skeletons",
                          "Chocolate Wands", "Choco-Loco", "Cockroach Clusters",
                          "Nougat", "Crystallised Pineapple",
                          "Drooble's Best Blowing Gum", "Exploding Bonbons",
                          "Toffees", "Fizzing Whizzbees",
                          "Fudge Flies", "Ice Mice",
                          "Jelly Slugs", "Liquourice Wands",
                          "Pepper Imps", "Peppermint Toads",
                          "Pink Coconut Ice", "Pixie Puffs",
                          "Pumpkin Fizz", "Salt Water Taffy",
                          "Shock-o-Choc", "Skeletal Sweets",
                          "Splindle's Lick'O'Rish Spiders",
                          "Sugar Quills", "Sugared Butterfly Wings",
                          "Toothflossing Stringmints", "Tooth-Splintering Strongmints",
                          "Treacle Fudge", "Chocolates", "Wizochoc"};
        JList candyList = new JList(candy);
        candyList.setVisibleRowCount(18);
        candyList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        ListSelectionListener sl = new ListSelectionListener() {
           public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
                String currentCard = (String)candyList.getSelectedValue();
            }
           }
        };

        candyList.addListSelectionListener(sl);

        //Creating a scrollpane for the JList
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(candyList, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                             JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        invntryPanel.add(scroll);


        //Creating the cards
        JPanel startCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel acidPopsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel batsBloodSoupCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel bertieBottsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel bloodPopsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel cauldronCakesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel charmChocCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocoballsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocCauldronsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocFrogsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocSkeleCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocWands = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocolocoCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel roachClustersCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel nougatCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel crystalPineappleCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel droobleGumCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel explodeBonbonsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel toffeesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel fizzWhizCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel fudgeFliesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel iceMiceCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel jellySlugsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel liquorWandsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pepImpsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pepToadsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pinkCocoIceCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pixiePuffsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel pumpkFizzCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel saltTaffeyCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel shockChocCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel skeleSweetsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel spindleSpidersCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel sugarQuillsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel sugarWingsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel flossMintsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel splintMintsCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel treacleFudgeCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel chocolatesCard = new JPanel();
        JPanel wizochocCard = new JPanel();

        //Adding the cards to the infoPanel
        infoPanel.add(startCard, "Start");
        infoPanel.add(acidPopsCard, "Acid Pops");
        infoPanel.add(batsBloodSoupCard, "Bat's Blood Soup");
        infoPanel.add(bertieBottsCard, "Bertie Bott's Every Flavour Beans");
        infoPanel.add(bloodPopsCard, "Blood-flavoured Lollipops");
        infoPanel.add(cauldronCakesCard, "Cauldron Cakes");
        infoPanel.add(charmChocCard, "Charm Choc");
        infoPanel.add(chocoballsCard, "Chocoballs");
        infoPanel.add(chocCauldronsCard, "Chocolate Cauldrons");
        infoPanel.add(chocFrogsCard, "Chocolate Frogs");
        infoPanel.add(chocSkeleCard, "Chocolate Skeletons");
        infoPanel.add(chocWands, "Chocolate Wands");
        infoPanel.add(chocolocoCard, "Choco-Loco");
        infoPanel.add(roachClustersCard, "Cockroach Clusters");
        infoPanel.add(nougatCard, "Nougat");
        infoPanel.add(crystalPineappleCard, "Crystallised Pineapple");
        infoPanel.add(droobleGumCard, "Drooble's Best Blowing Gum");
        infoPanel.add(explodeBonbonsCard, "Exploding Bonbons");
        infoPanel.add(toffeesCard, "Toffees");
        infoPanel.add(fizzWhizCard, "Fizzing Whizzbees");
        infoPanel.add(fudgeFliesCard, "Fudge Flies");
        infoPanel.add(iceMiceCard, "Ice Mice");
        infoPanel.add(jellySlugsCard, "Jelly Slugs");
        infoPanel.add(liquorWandsCard, "Liquourice Wands");
        infoPanel.add(pepImpsCard, "Pepper Imps");
        infoPanel.add(pepToadsCard, "Peppermint Toads");
        infoPanel.add(pinkCocoIceCard, "Pink Coconut Ice");
        infoPanel.add(pixiePuffsCard, "Pixie Puffs");
        infoPanel.add(pumpkFizzCard, "Pumpkin Fizz");
        infoPanel.add(saltTaffeyCard, "Salt Water Taffy");
        infoPanel.add(shockChocCard, "Shock-o-Choc");
        infoPanel.add(skeleSweetsCard, "Skeletal Sweets");
        infoPanel.add(spindleSpidersCard, "Splindle's Lick'O'Rish Spiders");
        infoPanel.add(sugarQuillsCard, "Sugar Quills");
        infoPanel.add(sugarWingsCard, "Sugared Butterfly Wings");
        infoPanel.add(flossMintsCard, "Toothflossing Stringmints");
        infoPanel.add(splintMintsCard, "Tooth-Splintering Strongmints");
        infoPanel.add(treacleFudgeCard, "Treacle Fudge");
        infoPanel.add(chocolatesCard, "Chocolates");
        infoPanel.add(wizochocCard, "Wizochoc");

        //startCard building
        JLabel startLbl = new JLabel("<html><center>Welcome to the Honeydukes Muggle Ordering System!<br />Please select from one of our products to the left to begin!</center></html>");
        startCard.add(startLbl, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.add(invntryPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        this.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
ClientApp.java:54: error: local variable candyList is accessed from within inner
 class; needs to be declared final
                                String currentCard = (String)candyList.getSelect
edValue();
                                                             ^
Note: ClientApp.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListSelectionListener is an interface and you can't just create one by simply using a constructor. You must instantiate a concrete class only, possibly an abstract inner class for this. So do that:

```
ListSelectionListener sl = new ListSelectionListener() {
   // place the necessary method(s) here as dictated by the interface
};
```

Since this is homework, I'll leave it to you to figure out what method(s) are needed, but the tutorial on using a JList and the [tutorial on writing a ListSelectionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) can help you out.

**Edit**
Also, are you importing all the classes you need? Including the ListSelectionListener class?

i.e.,
`import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;`

Comment: Aah, that would make sense. I suspected that it could be something like that, but I wasn't certain. Good to know, and thank you for the help!

Comment: I believe I should be. The ListSelectionListener seems to be under javax.swing.event, and I'm importing all of javax.swing, as well as java.util and java.awt.

Comment: @Sam: no, you're not. Importing a folder of classes such as javax.swing.* does not import any of its branches. You still are missing the import. Check the tutorial or sample code. You still need `javax.swing.event.*`

Comment: Noted, and hopefully fixed. Added import javax.swing.event.*; to my code.

Comment: Made a bit of progress, mostly thanks to you. The ListSelectionListener code has been put in directly after the JList.

Now, the tutorials used the indexes of the JList's array. Would it be possible to get the Strings instead of indexes, perhaps even using the show method of the CardLayout class to change the current card from within the Listener?

Original question has been updated with the current error the compiler' giving me, and the new code I've written. Thank you so much for everything. You've been a tremendous help.